# Trying to add multiple ID's to twitter tweet function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-oauth, discord.js

Everything is working fine here, but when I try to make an array to add multiple IDs I get an error.

```
follow: ['1046961121792614402', '1000086816572112896']
```

This only returns an error when adding more than one ID. Any feedback? Thanks

```
Error Status 401.

    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:555:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
```

Whole code:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

/**
 * Stream statuses filtered by keyword
 * number of tweets per second depends on topic popularity
 **/
const stream = (bot) => {
  client.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: ['104696112179261440', '1231231'] },
    function (stream) {
      stream.on('data',
        function (tweet) {
          bot.guilds.get('432635411726346').channels.get('432635264580097').send('Hi');
        });

      stream.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
};

module.exports = {
 client, stream 
};
```

Comment: Hi! Please can you add all the code you've written? Otherwise it is hard for us to see where the error is.

Comment: Sure, here. https://hastebin.com/nolocuguno.js